# react-navigation 5 - how to test navigation event listeners using Enzyme + Jest (react native)

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, enzyme, react-navigation-v5

I have implemented a focus listener in my component like so (as shown in the react-navigation v5 documentation):

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { navigation } = this.props
  this._unsubscribeFocus = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
    // do something
  })
}
```

I am struggling with finding a way to write a unit test for this using Jest/ Enzyme. I have tried using `wrapper.simulate('focus')` however, this doesn't seem to make the callback run.

Does anyone have any ideas/ experience with testing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best approach but let's try

```
focusCallback = () => {
    // do something
  }
componentDidMount() {
  const { navigation } = this.props
  this._unsubscribeFocus = navigation.addListener('focus', focusCallback)
}
```

// test file

```
wrapper.instance().focusCallback();
```

however this will still not cover below line

```
  this._unsubscribeFocus = navigation.addListener('focus', focusCallback)
```